# How do I prevent the verticalscrollbar in flowlayoutPanel to carousel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` with 50 `UserControl` and I use `this.KeyPreview = true`
to catch the event `KeyUp` in the event handler `Form1_KeyUp` in the form.

So I can either move the scrollbar manually and select a `UserControl` or step to the next or previous `UserControl` in the `FlowLayoutPanel` by using arrow keyUp or arrow key down buttons. The one that is selected has another background.
This works perfect except when at the entpoint.

But there is a problem when I click the arrow up when displaying `UserControl` in index 0 the `VerticalScrollbar` will carousel to the end and when click arrow down when displaying index 49 it will carousel to the beginning.

I have googled for preventing `VerticalScrollbar` to carousel in general or
for `FlowLayoutPanel` but there is nothing about this.

Any hints are helpful.

//Tony

Comment: i found the solution i just used  flowLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Value and  flowLayoutPanel1.performLayout()

Comment: You can use [`panel.ScrollControlIntoView(someControl);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview(v=vs.110).aspx)